# calculate age, returns NaN

Tags: javascript

I am trying to calculate age, only years but it is not working.
my code:

```
 function btn() {
            var txtYear = document.getElementById("txtYear").value;
            var dt = new Date();
            var year = dt.getYear;
            var age = year - txtYear;

            alert(age);//returns NaN
        }
```

Comment: `var txtYear = +document.....`

Comment: for one, you're trying to do math with a string (txtYear).

Comment: A missing cast is not the issue; `2015 - "20" == 1995`

Comment: `alert(year)` and `alert(txtYear+1)` will hopefully narrow it down for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dt.getYear` is a function, now you store a reference to this function in the `year` variable.

You need to call the function: `var year = dt.getYear()`, but [`getYear`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getYear) returns the short form and is deprecated. You should use `.getFullYear()` which returns, well, the full year.

```
 function btn() {
        var txtYear = document.getElementById("txtYear").value;
        var dt = new Date();
        var year = dt.getFullYear();
        var age = year - txtYear;

        alert(age);
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ybh1qy60/